Problem with rendereing geotiff file in proper bounds with openlayers
I have the code in openlayers 6.
which load the geotiff file - pacific.tif and in some viewers it says it has my projection WGS 84 (my openlayers projection is EPSG:4326).
which load the geotiff file - pacific.tif
And in some viewers it says it has my projection WGS 84 (my openlayers projection is EPSG:4623).
  const projection = new Projection({
    code: 'EPSG:4326',
    worldExtent: [-180, 90, 360, -90],
    unit: 'degrees'
  });

  source = new GeoTIFF({
      sources: [
        {
          url: url,
          projection: projection,
          unit: 'degrees'
        },
      ],
      wrapX: true,
      normalize: false,
      interpolate: true,
      projection: 'EPSG:4326'
    })

Then in the code tile layer creation
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/WebGLTile.js';


let view = await source.getView()

  let tileLayer = new TileLayer({
    visible: true,
    wrapX: true,
    source: source,
    extent: view.extent,
    style: geotiffCase
  })

which is added to map.
And it uses the bounds I attached on picture.

But it draw it from west to the east as view.extent = [ -80, -60, 119, 65], not from the east to the west crossing antimeridian. So the pacific.tif renders on atlantic ocean
I have tried to update in runtime source.getView().extent and source.getView().center where I put modified values (119 and 360-80 and it delta as center) and it code draw color in a proper place. but it is not the content of pacific.tif just my color for the empty value...
so how to fix the problem?
Is it possible to solve it from openlayers side with proper settings or additional code?
link to the pacific.tif

Can you provide a link to your pacific.tif?

@Mike thank you for your fast responce. I have added the link to the file. it was a quest to add 20mb here. also here again the link to the file https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/6cumsjl0d5tkyq816i9ad/pacific.tif?rlkey=nv36jpvhxjkmj4ikx7igsa2rr&e=2&st=tn01ekwm&dl=0

I get the same result with https://app.geotiff.io/load (which does not use OpenLayers).  Examining the source object in Openlayers the ModelTiepoint is [0, 0, 0, -80.00000000000003, 65, 0] which indicates the tile origin [-80, 65].  To work correctly the origin should be the top left somewhere in Asia, perhaps [120, 65].  Note the coast of Chile can be seen in the image https://i.sstatic.net/Qs2biPAn.png so it extends across the pacific beyond the -80 meridian.

The grid is offset by 180 degrees. You could use a custom projection and coordinate transforms to move it to the correct position https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-jgzkoj?file=index.html,package.json,index.js

@Mike your answer is incredible. I have asked for a luck. But you actually did it. I think this is proper answer and it should be posted as an answer - so i would able to approve it. Anyway direct copy to my vue project with openlayer 6 project isn't helped. so probably need to raise the linrary version or bother tif author.
